# How to only grab the link using R

Tags: r, xml, stringr, xml2

```
<item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="itemWithRetweets" link="http://twitter.com/MEDClementz/statuses/1001775473305817090" id="1001775473305817090">
```

How to grab only link and id out from the above ^

the output desired:

```
       link                                                         
[1] http://twitter.com/MEDClementz/statuses/1001775473305817090    
           id
[1] 1001775473305817090
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use xml parser instead of using regular expression

```
library(xml2)
x <- read_xml('<item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="itemWithRetweets" link="http://twitter.com/MEDClementz/statuses/1001775473305817090" id="1001775473305817090"></item>')

xml_attr(x,"link")
xml_attr(x,"id")
```

result:

```
> xml_attr(x,"link")
[1] "http://twitter.com/MEDClementz/statuses/1001775473305817090"
> xml_attr(x,"id")
[1] "1001775473305817090"
```

Comment: thank you for your help! however when I tried to read a list of lists, it returns only the first row .  Warning messages:
1: In if (grepl("<|>", x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In charToRaw(enc2utf8(x)) :
  argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored

Comment: I cannot work on it unless you give me an example. You can open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to use the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)

# Create the example string
string <- '<item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="itemWithRetweets" link="http://twitter.com/MEDClementz/statuses/1001775473305817090" id="1001775473305817090">'

# Split the string
string2 <- str_split(string, pattern = " ")[[1]]

# Get the link
link <- str_subset(string2, "link")
link2 <- str_extract(link, "http://.*[0-9]+")
link2
# [1] "http://twitter.com/MEDClementz/statuses/1001775473305817090"

# Get the id
id <- str_subset(string2, "id")
id2 <- str_extract(id, "[0-9]+")
id2
# [1] "1001775473305817090"
```

Comment: It works perfect for one string, however, it does not work for a list. How to select every [4]  of the [[1]]?

Comment: @YvonneDong Your example is only a string, so my answer is for one string. It is possible to use `lapply` or `purrr:map` to iterate the operation through the list. But without a reproducible, there is nothing I can do.